# ASP.NET - How to find a control in ListView from a dropdown list SelectMethod attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, drop-down-menu

I have a ListView which contains a label and a dropdown list. I would like to find the label by using `FindControl()` from the SelectMethod attribute of the dropdown list. Here's my code:

**.aspx:**

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID"
    ItemType="Models.Items" SelectMethod="GetItem">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="LabelItemId" runat="server"
            Text="<%#: Item.ID %>"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
            SelectMethod="GetCategories" ItemType="Models.Category"
            DataValueField="CategoryID" DataTextField="CategoryName">
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

**C#:**

```
protected void GetCategories(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var db = new ItemContext())
        {
            var dropDownList = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("DropDownList1");
            IQueryable<Category> query = db.Categories;
            List<Category> categories = query.ToList();

            //The line below is the problem because e is null
            var item = categories.First(category => category.CategoryID == 
                    Convert.ToInt32(((Label)e.Item.FindControl("LabelItemId")).Text));
        }
    }
```

The problem is the `e` of `ListViewItemEventArgs` is null. So, I got a `NullReferenceException`. Maybe the reason is that I should not be using `ListViewItemEventArgs` for `SelectMethod` attribute. If that's the case, what should I use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `OnDataBound` attribute to `DropDownList` and write this method for the `OnDataBound` event:

**C#:**

```
        protected void DropDownList1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                var control = (Control)sender;
                var lvi = (ListViewItem)control.NamingContainer;
                var label = (Label)lvi.FindControl("LabelCategoryId");
                string text = label.Text;
                var ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
                ddl.SelectedValue = text;
            }
```

This will change the `SelectedValue` of the `DropDownList` according to the label text of each item in the `ListView`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate a loop to get the label value as follows:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in ListView1.Items)
{
    Label mylabel = (Label)item.FindControl("Label1");
    lblID.Text = mylabel.Text;
}
```

**Note:** This will do for other controls as well.

If it doesn't work, there is another solution. Do the following:

```
ListViewItem item = ListView1.Items[ListView1.SelectedIndex];  
Label myLabel = (Label)item.FindControl("Label1");

string result = myLabel.text; //Get the text here
```

Comment: When I use foreach, it does not even enter the foreach loop. This is weird because it is as if my listview does not have any item but it does.

Comment: I've updated the post. See if it helps. It works perfect on my side.

Comment: In what event should I put the code ? Currently, I put it inside my dropdownlist `SelectMethod` attribute because I want the `SelectedValue` of the dropdownlist to be the same with the label text. When I try your new code, it still says there's no item in my `listview`. It seems like the `listview` is not yet loaded.

Comment: Nevermind, I've found the solution. I fire the `OnDataBound` event of the `dropdownlist` then I use the `object sender` argument to access the `ListViewItem`'s `NamingContainer` property. From there, I was able to use `FindControl()` to get the label text.